# Karma/jasmine No provider for Http when using httpclientmodule

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I am trying to migrate my tests to use the new HttpClientmodule instead of the old Httpmodule.

I keep getting the error Error: No provider for Http! for my service tests.

Here is my testbed.

```js
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http'
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { AppConfig } from './app.config';
import { APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import {
    Http,
    ConnectionBackend,
    BaseRequestOptions,
    Response,
    ResponseOptions
} from '@angular/http';

export function initConfig(config: AppConfig) {

    return () => config.loadForTest();
}


describe('AuthService', () => {

    beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, HttpClientModule],
        providers:[
        AppConfig,
    HttpClientModule,
            {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: initConfig,
            deps: [AppConfig],
            multi: true
        },
            AuthService,]
    }));

    it('should get user', () => {
        debugger;
        let authService = TestBed.get(AuthService);
        const http = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
        // fake response
        const expectedUser = {
            username: 'username' };

        let actualUser = {};
        authService.GetActiveProfile().subscribe((user) => {
            actualUser = user;
        });
        let baseuri = window.location.origin;
        let requesturi = '/user/activeprofile';
        http.expectOne(baseuri + requesturi).flush(expectedUser);

        expect(actualUser).toEqual(expectedUser);
    });
});
```

Do I need to also implement the old http? From what I could see form the guides that I have read from migrating from http -> httpclient this should not be the case?

Authservice

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
import { AppConfig } from './app.config';
import { ActiveProfile } from './balancing/models/ActiveProfile';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    errorMessage: string;

    headers: HttpHeaders;
 

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private config: AppConfig) {

        this.headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=-8');
             
            this.GetActiveProfile();
    }
    
    GetActiveProfile(): Observable<ActiveProfile> {
      
        let baseuri = window.location.origin;
        let requesturi = '/user/activeprofile';
        let request = baseuri + requesturi;

        return this.http.get<ActiveProfile>(request, { headers: this.headers, withCredentials: true }).map(
            response => this.storeCurrentUser(response), (err: HttpErrorResponse) => { this.handleError(err) })
    }

    private storeCurrentUser(res: ActiveProfile) {
        localStorage.setItem('currentuser', JSON.stringify(res));

        return res;
    }

    GetCurrentUser(): ActiveProfile {
        debugger;
        let currentuser = localStorage.getItem('currentuser');
        let parseduser = JSON.parse(currentuser);
        return parseduser as ActiveProfile;
    }


    private handleError(err) {
        if (err.error instanceof Error) {
            // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly
            console.log('An error occured:', err.error.message);
        }
        else {
            // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
            // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
            console.log(`Backend returned code ${err.status}, body was: ${err.error}`);
        }
    }
}

export const AUTH_PROVIDERS: Array<any> = [

    { provide: AuthService, useClass: AuthService }
];
```

Comment: Where do you use `Http`?

Comment: Added service code where I am doing my requests.

Comment: Post the exact an dcomplete error you get. This error probably comes from another test, that still uses Http, or loads a service or library that still uses Http.

Comment: Ah, now I see what it is. It was your comment about other libraries that made me realize that my Appconfig still used Http. Thanks for the input! Hard to trace that from the error message though.